# How can I authenticate users using DotNetOpenAuth with an Active Directory provider?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, active-directory, openid, dotnetopenauth

I am trying to integrate authentication for a cloud-based application with an Active Directory forest behind my cilent's firewall.

I am a Python developer from the open-source world... needless to say, .NET is not my forte and I'm not familiar with authentication technologies provided by IIS/WIF/etc.

**I have installed DotNetOpenAuth** and gotten the sample MVC OpenID provider working with the included ReadOnlyXmlMembershipProvider.

I have scoured Google for a sample config/implementation or any documentation at all that describes the appropriate membership provider to use. The only thing I have found are hints - "It's included out of the box," or "create a .NET app that authenticates off of AD and expose OpenID."

**How can I query off my client's AD? Is there a provider included with DNoA?**